# How to load bodypix model from local disk?

Tags: tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

My app can't connect Internet all the time, and how to load trained bodypix from local disk? The nodejs code snippet

```
    const net = await bodyPix.load({
        architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
        outputStride: 16,
        multiplier: 0.75,
        quantBytes: 2,
    });
```

In README.md I found

> modelUrl - An optional string that specifies custom url of the model. 
>   This is useful for local development or countries that don't have access > to the models hosted on GCP.

Could you please give me an example what the url is of the local model? and what's the content of the dest model (BTW: how can I download the trained model?). Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a bodypix model locally you need to download, and host the model's `json`, and `.bin` files then access them using the `modelUrl` option.

Eg:

```
const net = await bodyPix.load({
    architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
    outputStride: 16,
    multiplier: 0.75,
    quantBytes: 2,
    modelUrl: "/public/model-stride16.json"
});
```

The url passed to `modelUrl` must be a valid url.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Progressive Web Apps if you want to be able to use JavaScript offline like an App.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-beginners-guide-to-progressive-web-apps/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers

Comment: The original question has been edited to clarify that the code is a "nodejs code snippet", for which service workers are not available. While this answer is correct for web apps where self hosting is not neccessary, it does not help with nodejs.

Comment: Ah I see. The bodypix wrapper the team made makes a fetch to server to grab the model files. I guess it wouldn't be too hard to fork that and cache those files locally so it then loads from disk instead? Only way I can think of.

Comment: Since you have to polyfill fetch on NodeJS anyways, the best way would probably be to  hijack fetch to pull from a local cache, or fallback to network. That way you don't need to deal with format/location changes, etc, in their files. All you do is cache every request for next time.